# Error when i import a class from iOS 7 to iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiview, types

I import a animation class. And this class is downloaded class. In iOS 8 there is no framework added. And when i run the app its showing so many errors. Like:

```
Unknown type name 'UIView'
Expected a type
```

like this so many errors coming. I am sharing my Screenshot please anybody can help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can avoid this error. Just import this:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

[image]

It's solve your problem :)